# Local css working but server isn't - is this to do with bundling / debug?

Tags: css, asp.net

The following is a section of code take directly from my CSS. On my local build it's working just how it should creating 3 borders around the main display. However when published on my server the CSS isn't taking any effect. Even the radius - it's almost like it's getting overwritten and I'm not sure how I can fix it. I'm fairly new to the scene and am happy to provide any useful information I can to help find the issue. My question is why would it be overwritten when live but not on local - would this be something to do with debug mode maybe?

Note: after disabling debug mode in web.config it's also not working.

```
.container-fluid .jumbotron {
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    box-shadow: 
        0 0 0 3px #FFC800, 
        0 0 0 6px #FF7801,
        0 0 0 9px #D70000;
```

Comment: Have a look in the browser console. Are there any 404 errors? I've a suspicion that the required CSS isn't being delivered.

Comment: the information's that you have provide is not enough  to get any answer, I only can assume that this incomplete css line, is on a separate css file that your page fail to load because you do not call it on correct path. Open yours browsers debug tools to see what css and load errors do you have ( the debug have nothing to do with this)

Comment: There are no errors in the console. Again, the code is called and is working on local. Only when it's uploaded or debug is turned to false is it not getting displayed.

This is within bootstrap.css.

It seems to be when debug is not active, the style sheet is not called in the same way. I feel this may well be a bundle issue.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed with  BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = False within application start.